# How to remove insignificant whitespace in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, whitespace

Given any document or fragment, specially those loaded using `document()` or `doc()`, how do you remove the insignificant whitespace (i.e. indentation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="*[* and not(text()[normalize-space()])]/text()"/>
```